# In FormatConditions how do i make the "if" code as dynamic for all F column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change "$F1" to cell(i,6) but its not working....why?

```
Sub macro2()
    Dim i As Long

        For i = 1 To 2

    Cells(i, 6).Select
    With Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5))
         .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
         "=IF(***$F1***>5,TRUE,FALSE)"
                     With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5287936
                .TintAndShade = 0

           End With

        End With

    End With


    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: As implied in @Jeeped's answer, you never need an IF in a conditional formatting formula. Here's a post I did on the topic: http://yoursumbuddy.com/no-ifs-in-conditional-formatting-formulas/

Answer (score 0):

You could try,

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
   "=IF($F" & i & ">5, TRUE, FALSE)"
```

... but that formula is redundant. This produces *exactly* the same boolean results.

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
   "=$F" & i & ">5"
```

The formula you are using *is* dynamic. You do not need to loop through the rows. A CF rule formula acts as if it is an R1C1 formula; i.e. they are exactly the same for every cell in the *Applies to:* range. You could also set all of the *i* cells at once and avoid the loop.

```
with activesheet
    with .range("F1:F2")
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= "=$F1>5"
        with .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = 5287936
        end with
    end with
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it seems that the range you want to apply the `FormatConditions` is `A1:E2`. Also the `FormatConditions` is to be based on the value of column `F` for each `Row`. If this is correct then use the code below:

```
Sub FormatConditions_Dynamic()
Dim rRow As Range
For Each rRow In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E2").Rows
    With rRow
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=" & Cells(.Row, 6).Address(0) & ">5"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5287936
                .TintAndShade = 0
End With: End With: End With: Next
End Sub
```